# Python code repeats 8 times when not necessary

Tags: python

```
def Reset():
    global seven_digit
    seven_digit = ["","","","","","",""]
    global x
    x = 0
    global eight
    eight = 0
    global c
    c = 0
    cinput()
def cinput():
    global thing
    print("Enter digit ", x+1)
    thing = input("")
    check()
def check():
    global eight
    global x
    if not thing.isdigit():
        print("That character is not allowed")
        cinput()
    elif len(thing) > 1:
        print("Those characters are not allowed")
        cinput()
    if x < 7:
        seven_digit[x] = int(thing)
        x += 1
        cinput()
   if x == 7:
        eight = int(thing)
        fcheck()
def fcheck(): #this section is temporary just for testing
    global c 
    c+=1
    print("This is c, ", c)
    print("Test")
    print(seven_digit)
    print(eight)
Reset()
```

This is the code I have been developing as an a-level task (it is this years GCSE course) however I have stumbled across a problem where the last section in the self-created function of fcheck() repeats itself 8 times. I have used a similar process before in python and I have never seen an error like it before. I was wondering if anyone knew what I could do to fix it, thanks.

Comment: The code 'if elif' under check() should be moved to cinput() after statement  - thing = input(). Recursion happens because of which fcheck() repeats

Comment: Among all the global statements and lack of whitespace or comments I'm curious - what is that wall of code even meant to do?

Comment: @unMask, there is no recursion here. There is a chain of calls, but this is not recursion, no function calls itself.

Comment: @JonClements At the minute it is only meant to assign the first 7 digits inputted into the array and the 8th digit into the separate variable 'eight' however, when the task is completed it is meant to check whether or not someone's card is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mutual calling between `check` and `cinput`, so, it you call `fcheck` inside this chain of calls, it will be called 8 times.

If you want to call `fcheck` once, after the all evaluation chain, you can just remove the call to it at the last line of `check`, and call it at the end of `Reset`:

```
def Reset():
    global seven_digit
    seven_digit = ["","","","","","",""]
    global x
    x = 0
    global eight
    eight = 0
    global c
    c = 0
    cinput()
    fcheck()

def cinput():
    global thing
    print("Enter digit ", x+1)
    thing = str(input(""))
    check()

def check():
    global eight
    global x
    if not thing.isdigit():
        print("That character is not allowed")
        cinput()
    elif len(thing) > 1:
        print("Those characters are not allowed")
        cinput()
    if x < 7:
        seven_digit[x] = int(thing)
        x += 1
        cinput()
    if x == 7:
        eight = int(thing)

def fcheck(): #this section is temporary just for testing
    global c
    c+=1
    print("This is c, ", c)
    print("Test")
    print(seven_digit)
    print(eight)

Reset()
```